# Need Dynamic Insertion Query for Following Code

Tags: c#, sql

For following code I don't know the listbox item before execution so I need dynamic query for selection for following code;

```
            string selectedTable = cmbImportItemList.Text;

            string col1 = opLstCsl3.Items[0].ToString();
            string col2 = opLstCsl3.Items[1].ToString();
            string col3 = opLstCsl3.Items[2].ToString();
            string col4 = opLstCsl3.Items[3].ToString();
            string col5 = opLstCsl3.Items[4].ToString();
            string col6 = opLstCsl3.Items[5].ToString();
            string col7 = opLstCsl3.Items[6].ToString();
            string col8 = opLstCsl3.Items[7].ToString();
            //string[] coll = new string[100];
            //string col9 = opLstCsl3.Items[8].ToString();
            //'"+col1+"','"+col2+"','"+col3+"','"+col4+"'
            using (SqlDataAdapter adater = new SqlDataAdapter("Select " + col1 + "," + col2 + "," + col3 + "," + col4 + "," + col5 + "," + col6 + "," + col7 + "," + col8 + " from " + selectedTable, new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.connectionstring2)))
            {
                adater.Fill(dttt);
            }
```

Comment: You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: It would be much easier to use a stored procedure!

Comment: Can you give me some guidance regarding to write store procedure for same query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a stored procedure for your query, first execute this in your database,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetData @colName nvarchar(500) = NULL,@tableName nvarchar(50)=NULL
AS
DECLARE @sqlText nvarchar(1000); 
SET @sqlText = N'SELECT ' + @colName + ' FROM ' + @tableName
Exec (@sqlText)
GO
```

and make your columns are comma separated ones like below

```
string selectedTable = cmbImportItemList.Text;
string columns = string.Empty;
foreach (var item in pLstCsl3.Items)
{
   columns += item + ',';
}
```

and finally call the stored procedure like below,

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.connectionstring2)) {
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd  = new SqlCommand("GetData", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@colName", columns));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tableName", selectedTable));

    using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            // do what ever you want with your records.
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

If you want understand about stored procedures refer following links,
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126898/Sql-Server-How-to-write-a-Stored-procedure-in-Sql

Thanks
Sivan

Comment: if it is works for you, mark this is an answer, Thanks.